# NSMutableArray does not take a replaced object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, replace, nsmutablearray

I am using a NSMutableArray in which certain elements are there, at a part of coding i replace a object(NSString) with another object(NSString) then the element is replaced but on the another part of coding when i used that array with a loop then it will leave the index of replaced object and iterate the rest loop completly

the code for replace object are...

```
lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:buttonValue + 250];
    NSString *str = lbl.text;
    for (int i=0; i< [appDelegate.dataArray count]; i++){
        if ([appDelegate.dataArray objectAtIndex:i] == lbl.text)
        {
            [appDelegate.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:city];
        }
    }
```

code for reusing array with loop are...

```
for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.dataArray count];i++){
        dictionary = [appDelegate.countryListArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"countryCity"]];
    if ([sLocation isEqualToString:str] ){
        sLocation = [dictionary valueForKey:@"continentCity"];
    }
```

Comment: I can't really follow what you're trying to do, but at a guess, you may want to add a `break` statement after you set `sLocation`.

Comment: my question is that why the loop is not taking the replaced object after replacing object

Comment: I don't actually understand your question. You are not even using the same array. I mean, you are counting up to the same number in dataArray, but you are never, ever actually /accessing/ it in the second loop.

Comment: What does "taking the replaced object" mean? It's hard to understand what you're saying is not happening.

Comment: accessing the different array is some other part of my code but on the second loop all the object\ that are in the appDelegate.dataArray are not iterated the loop leave the replaced object

Comment: Based on the code you provided in the question, your array counts would be constant. Whether or not you ever replaced a value seems completely irrelevant since it 1) wouldn't effect the count of the array; and 2) you never access the element in the original array anyway. Finally, Chuck is right, you probably rarely if ever even replace elements since there's a good chance the result of your objectAtIndex: method != the result of lbl.text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code compare the object contents, not the object address code change:

```
if ([appDelegate.dataArray objectAtIndex:i] == lbl.text)
```

to

```
if ([[appDelegate.dataArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:lbl.text])
```

In the second code `appDelegate.dataArray` is never referenced so the change has no effect.

Also what is: `sLocation`?

Comment: my problems remains the same please help me

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares pointer equality. The strings may have the same contents, but they are most likely not the same exact object. You want `[[appDelegate.dataArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:lbl.text]`.

Comment: after doing this my problems remains same please help me